Ubuntu 22 ext4 performance tuning (metadata)
I have Ubuntu 22 with 5.15.0-106-generic kernel.
I have a jbod with 60 hdd attached and working with a lot of small files.
I need that RAM will store only metadata and not file itself. I'm working with vfs cache pressure a little but I'm not sure what is the best settings.
How can I set my server to use RAM to store primarly metadata?

consider using a file system optimized for handling a large number of small files, such as XFS or Btrfs, as they can provide better performance and scalability compared to traditional file systems like ext4.

This is in my future plan for new server coming but now I need to optimize what I have. ext4 and 1tb of ram :)

So I guess you got to play with vm.swappiness vm.pagecache_limit_mb vm.vfs_cache_pressure and vm.dirty_* sysctl parameters and see live how it feets with your activity and ressources.

ext4 doesn't have a lot of knobs to tweak for this.  Keeping number of files in a directory under 100 may help.  For zfs and xfs , keep the number under 1000.

If you have a lot of small files and they are read only, consider making squashfs images for directory trees and mounting them...   squashfs is ideal for small files.
